# `GetChangesResponse does not implement inherited abstract member 'ProtoData.RawProto.get'` when creating Xamarin Android binding

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I'm trying to make a Xamarin Android Native binding for https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/get-started. I keep getting the error `GetChangesResponse does not implement inherited abstract member 'ProtoData.RawProto.get'`.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? I have added the line `<attr path="/api/package[@name='androidx.health.platform.client.request']/class[@name='GetChangesTokenRequest']/method[starts-with(@name, 'get') and count(parameter)=0]" name="propertyName"></attr>` to metadata.xml. but that doesn't work.